# Accessing the table view cell a certain object is in: Legal to access the cell via superview?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, core-data, nsfetchedresultscontroller

I have a very variable table view which can be edited by a user in several ways at once. Add, Delete rows and rename text in textfields within these cells. So far I've accessed the cell indexPath with:

```
-(void)textFieldDidEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField
{
    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:textField.tag inSection:0];
    MainCategory *mainCategory = [self.fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];

    if(textField.text != mainCategory.name){
        mainCategory.name = textField.text;
    }

    self.activeField = nil;
}
```

However this gave problems after reorder, deletes etc. Now with this approach it works:

```
-(void)textFieldDidEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField
{
    //NSIndexPath *indexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:textField.tag inSection:0];

    // Get the cell in which the textfield is embedded
    id textFieldSuper = textField;
    while (![textFieldSuper isKindOfClass:[UITableViewCell class]]) {
        textFieldSuper = [textFieldSuper superview];
    }

    UITableViewCell *cell = textFieldSuper;
    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForCell:cell];
    MainCategory *mainCategory = [self.fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];

    if(textField.text != mainCategory.name){
        mainCategory.name = textField.text;
    }

    self.activeField = nil;
}
```

Is this a legal way to do it?

Comment: yes, its not a problem. i used superview kinda stuff many times.

Comment: Ok great..so I'm getting rid of all my tags..caused alot of problems...THX!

Answer (score 1):

It will work, but I prefer avoid using loops when not needed.

You could use this solution:

```
-(void)textFieldDidEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField
{
        CGPoint pnt = [self.tableView convertPoint:textField.bounds.origin fromView:textField];
        NSIndexPath* indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForRowAtPoint:pnt];

        MainCategory *mainCategory = [self.fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];

        if(textField.text != mainCategory.name){
             mainCategory.name = textField.text;
        }

        self.activeField = nil;
}
```